# Textfield width auto width | First take up horizontal space before dropping down a line

Tags: html, css

How can I make a textfield have an auto width that expands as the user types, until reaching the parents width, then dropping down (and expanding in height).

It seems as though width:auto doesn't even work for some reason.


Thanks.

Comment: What scenario would this be used rather than having the input at the maximum width? Just make the element width 100% or fiddle with [contenteditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) and clone contents to a form element.

Comment: @OfficialAntarctica The input text can't drop down if it becomes wider than the parent width.

Comment: Use the `textarea` element or use my answer below ↓

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it with an `input` element but you can cheat it.

Fork it on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/XpGvrp).

```js
$(".nice-input").keyup(function(){
   if($(`input[nice-rel="${$(this).attr("id")}"]`).length > 0) {
      $(`input[nice-rel="${$(this).attr("id")}"]`).val($(this).text());
   }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .input {
  font: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <span class="input nice-input" id="main" contenteditable="true"></span>
</div> 
<input type="text" nice-rel="main" placeholder="Hide this element" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: black;
}

textarea {
    width: 110px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function() {    
    // Increases the length of textarea
    $("textarea").css({
        'width' : $(this).width() + 10
    });

    // Increases the height when textarea width reaches maximum length
    if ($(this).width() >= $(this).parent().width()) {
        $(this).css({
            'height' : $(this).height() + 20
        })
    }
}
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxkyc72t/)

It almost works exactly as described. If anyone finds out a way to determine the width of the content inside of the text area it would achieve the goal. For now, you guys can use this as a stepping stone.